# How do I add a flag to a document class to show or not show portions of document?

Tags: beamer

I write quizzes in beamer. They typically look like:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\mode<presentation><>
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Quiz 1}
1. What is $1+2$?
{\color{blue} 3}
2. What is $a^2 \cdot a^3$?
{\color{blue} a^5}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have two questions with the answers in blue. Is there a way to add a flag which shows only the questions (without the flag), and shows the questions with the answers in blue with the flag? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at "overlay" in the beamer documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily define such a conditional with `\newif` and then define a command that shows the answers if the conditional is true (it is false once you've defined it) and doesn't shows them otherwise.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newif\ifAnswers
%\Answerstrue
\newcommand\Answer[1]{\ifAnswers\textcolor{blue}{#1}\else\relax\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Quiz 1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item What is $1+2$?
\Answer{$3$}
\item What is $a^2 \cdot a^3$?
\Answer{$a^5$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the line

```
%\Answerstrue
```

you'll see the answers.

### Remarks

1. Don't do numbering by hand. There's `enumerate` for numbered lists.
2. The color specification for the answers can be done in the defined command; this gives you easy code maintainability and enforces separation between form and content.